# PHP substring - getting the penultimate two strings after a slash /

Tags: php, url, substring, explode

```
<?php
$urlString = 'www.me.com/hello/world';
>
```

I'm trying to make `$arg1 = 'hello'` and `$arg2 = 'world'`

Comment: Have you tried using the functions you tagged? Take a look at `print_r(explode('/', $urlString));`.

Comment: I can get substring working (kinda) but I am at a loss to deal with the different string inputs lengths. I don't understand how to tell it to count the penultimate 2, and give me the number of chars inbetween. Explode I'm looking at but having similar issue

Comment: Well you posted a static string. If there are multiple variations you should supply a couple versions. As is you're going to get multiple answers just assuming you never tried the explode/substr.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<?php
$urlString = 'www.me.com/hello/world';
$args = explode("/",$urlString);

echo $args[1]; //hello
echo $args[2]; //world
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like [this](https://3v4l.org/PG0rO) :

```
$urlString = 'www.me.com/hello/world';
$values = explode("/", $urlString);
$arg1 = $values[1];
$arg2 = $values[2];

echo "Arg1: " . $arg1 . ' - ' . " Arg2: " . $arg2 . "\n";
# Arg1: hello - Arg2: world
```